# Abort Git Merge in PhpStorm

Tags: git, macos, phpstorm

#### Situation:

1. Merged a branch
2. Made a mistake while merging.
3. I need to abort the merge and start over.

I previously used [Tower for Mac](https://www.git-tower.com/) to manage my git repository. I'm trying to make the switch to using PhpStorm to manage my git repo but it seems to be missing some features.

In Tower there is an "Abort" button which allows me to easily undo my messed up merge and start over. Simply click the "Abort" button and it reverts everything perfectly like you never even started the merge.

[image: Tower for Mac Abort Merge Button]

*Tower for Mac Abort Merge Button*

#### Question:

Is there a simple way to abort/undo a merge in PhpStorm?

Comment: Did the merge actually complete (i.e. is there a merge commit), or do you have merge conflicts which have yet to be resolved?

Comment: The merge conflict is not complete. There are still conflicts that need to be resolved. I simply resolved one incorrectly and want to start the merge over.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**GUI**

In new versions of phpStorm use the function "Git" -> "Abort Merge". In old versions use "VCS" -> "Git" -> "Reset Head" and choose the "Hard" option.

You will lose all changes, so be careful.

[image: Screenshot]

**CLI**

git merge --abort

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to undo the changes to a single file `somefile` then you can try the following:

```
git checkout -- path/to/somefile
```

In case you want to undo the entire merge operation, then `git reset` will come in handy:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Both of these operations are resetting the state to the `HEAD` of the branch, which is the last commit made before you attemtped a merge.

Comment: I think the reson for the question is, to get information if there is any button in the phpstorm gui what can do this. Means the basic question is "Is there any gui button in phpstorm what makes the same like `git merge --abort`

Comment: there is a reason, look at my comment above. Your solution answer the question how to abort on commandline, but the question was, how to do this in phpstorm.
That means you are not answering the question of @zeckdc

Answer (score 0):

At least as of 2021, there is an Abort Merge option in the branch list that is opened when pressing the branch name in the bottom right of the IDE. It's at the very top of the branch list so make sure to scroll up. Credit to answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1476158/193217).